# Is this a good use case for Task Parallel Library?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I have a situation and need some advice. I'm calling Twitter to get retweets, replies, likes, and stuff like that.  Twitter, of course, rates limit your calls so I need to pace out my calls. And since I do not want to wait for a long time if one user is locked up because I still want to continue getting engagements for other users, I thought I should use multiple threads. As an experiment, I tried Parallel task library something like:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Parallel.ForEach<BatchJob>(jobsToProcess, job =>
{
    //call Twitter here
});
```

From testing, it seems that this was eating up a lot of CPU and froze the whole system. My question is: Is this a situation where using Parallel task will fit? I do not need to wait for one task to finish to start another. They all can run at the same time. In other words, the tasks do not depend on each other.

Comment: Code like this really should not freeze your system, I think. You should try to figure out what exactly is it doing and why is it so resource hungry.

Comment: One change, not bering on the TPL question, I would recommend is I would pass in `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` to the factory so it does not consume one of your thread-pool threads (It could potentially wait a long time for the list of jobs to finish)

Answer (score 1):

If it is in a context of an webApp, your call will be lost. Please view an session of build 2013 where they explain why. If It is a desktop application, it should work as long as you use "dispatcher" object to update your visual.

I don't like to use "task.factory", it's just me, but I prefer the syntax "new task (() => {...})

Edit : no parallel task won't change a thing.

It's meant as comment, can't find a link for comment

Comment: It's in a window service.